# Prevent div overlap with CSS

Tags: css, html, overlap, overlapping

I have a problem with divs overlapping in http://web.corporativocipres.com.mx/

The issue is with the links in the footer (Corporativo - Historias Memorables Area de Prensa) they have after a div with the classmidbg trans that works like background but it overlaps and the link is unclickable.

I tried with different z-index but didn't work (or maybe I done this bad).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `z-index: 1` to `midbg`, and add `position: relative; z-index: 2` to `.mid li`, you'll fix the problem.

The `z-index` property is definitely a weird one, and can act strangely when the `position` property isn't defined. Sometimes this is useful, sometimes it's not.

Comment: Thanks! that works I always have problems understanding the z-index, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the div:

```
<div class="midbg trans"></div>
```

And the `class="midbg trans"` class set to the li:

```
<li class="midbg trans"><a href="/memoriables">Historias Memorables</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the

```
<div class="midbg trans"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the midbg class you're using for making that darker background to the list element tags.

The z index requires the position property to be set, you can set position of elements absolutely within the footer if you want, and then use the z-index.